# Starting Redmine at boot using upstart on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, upstart, redmine

So after installing Redmine from the repositories on Ubuntu 12.04, I've tried to create an upstart script (see below) so it would start up at boot time.

While

```
service redmine start
```

does start Redmine, it does not start automatically when booting. Also when I run

```
service redmine stop
```

it does stop Redmine but simply hangs until I press ctrl+c

Also, after stopping starting it again does not work (Also just hangs).

According to all the upstart examples and tutorials I have seen this should work, so I guess I'm overlooking something. Any hints?

```
#Redmine
description "Redmine"

start on started networking
stop on stopping networking
stop on starting shutdown

console output

expect daemon
exec ruby /usr/share/redmine/script/server webrick -e production -b 188.40.184.155 -p 3000 -d

respawn
```

Comment: no concrete answer to your question -- but does the last line of your script really read "respaw", and not "respawn"?

Comment: No prob. Better there than in the upstart file itself :)

Answer (score 1):

Given the age of the question, and the fact that redmine has probably released various versions since then, I would imagine you got round the issues reported here ..

So, I am just commenting generally .. for posterity

If you can start the process normally, but it does not auto-start, it simply means the service is not set to auto-start.

Generally, you can enable a service to auto-start like so:

- If you have chkconfig installed:  `chkconfig redmine on`
- If not, `update-rc.d redmine enable`  (how you run this command can vary, depends on how you have setup the script .. run `man update-rc.d` to see more details)

You seem to be trying to setup redmine to run with webrick, but it is probably more efficient to set it up to run under passenger (and integrated into apache or nginx web servers).  If you are setup that way, then you would not need an upstart or init script, as passenger will connect to redmine for you on demand .. You can [read more here](http://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/wiki/HowTo_Install_Redmine_on_Ubuntu_step_by_step) ..